# Using nested NSPredicate SUBQUERY returning empty array

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

This is the relevant part of my object graph:

```m
Member_Profile <-->> Member_Posts <-->> Comment
```

[image: object_graph]

I'd like to be able to filter the posts by the member_id attribute, like this:

```m
@"(member_id == %@)"
```

And when a user selects a post then I'd like to be able to filter the comments for the selected post by the member_id attribute, like this:

```
memberPosts.comment.post_id == 7
```

I am trying to use a set of nested SUBQUERY predicates, like this:

```m
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(member_id == %@) AND (0 != SUBQUERY(memberPosts, $x, (0 != SUBQUERY($x.comment, $y, ANY $y.post_id == %@).@count)).@count)", _memberIDString, _postIDString];
```

This returns empty array at runtime

It seems like I'm on the right track, here, but can't find any other examples that use the same syntax. What am I missing?

## Edit 1:

Here is my complete `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```m
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchPostCommentsFromContext {

if (!_fetchPostCommentsFromContext) {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:MEMBER_PROFILE_ENTITY];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"member_id" ascending:YES]];        

    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(member_id = %@) AND (0 != SUBQUERY(memberPosts, $x, (0 != SUBQUERY($x.comment, $y, ANY $y.post_id = %@).@count)).@count)", _memberIDString, _memberPostObj.post_id];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContextObj= [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].persistentStoreManagedObjectContext;

    self.fetchPostCommentsFromContext = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContextObj sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    self.fetchPostCommentsFromContext.delegate = self;

    NSError *error;

    [self.fetchPostCommentsFromContext performFetch:&error];
    NSAssert(!error, @"Error performing fetch request: %@", error);

    NSLog(@"%@",[self.fetchPostCommentsFromContext fetchedObjects]);
}
return _fetchPostCommentsFromContext;
}
```

## Edit 2:

Here is the API request I am making to fetch `memberProfile`:

```m
- (void)requestMemberProfileAPI {

NSString *requestPath = [AndTunesConstants requestPath:MEMBER_PROFILE_API];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"member_id": _memberIdToFetchProfileData,
                              @"timestamp": @"0",
                              };

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]
 postObject:nil path:requestPath parameters:parameters success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResutl) {

     NSError *error;
     NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseData
                                                          options:kNilOptions
                                                            error:&error];
     if (error == nil)
     {
         if ([[json objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
         {

                 if (![self.fetchPostCommentsFromContext performFetch:&error])
                 {
//                     abort();
                 }

         } else {
             NSLog(@"Server Response False (status = false)");
         }
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Error in Serializing JSON (json not correct): %@", error.localizedDescription);
     }
 }
 failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     RKLogError(@"Load failed with error: %@", error);

 }];
}
```

Comment: Still trying to understand, you would like to get all members who have commented on a particular post_id? How do you know who made a comment?

Comment: No, I'd like to be able to filter the posts by the member_id attribute. And when a user selects a post then I'd like to be able to filter the comments for the selected post by the memberPosts.comment.post_id attribute.

Member<----->>memberPosts <----->> Comment

For example: When 'A' user views 'B' user's wall feed (screen 1). Then A should able to view all the posts of 'B'. And when 'A' user selects a post form 'B' user's wall. Then 'A' should be able to see all the comments related to selected post only...

Comment: Do you want to filter comments by member_id or post_id? Do you want to fetch members, comments or posts? What is the post_id attribute of Comment?

Comment: @Willeke Lets say 'A' user's member_ID is 123. What I want to achieve: **1st** Fetch posts of only user 'A'
**2nd** When a post is selected, fetch comments of selected post.

I want to fetch all 3 i.e. member, posts and comments but on different screens.

post_id attribute of Comment holds same vale as of Member_Posts (to uniquely identify comments for each post).

Comment: So post_id is identical to memberPosts?

Comment: @Willeke Yes, Comment post_id is identical to Member_Posts post_id...

Comment: Why do you have two properties with the same value? To fetch the posts of member A you create a fetch request with entity Member_Posts and predicate ("memberProfile == %@", memberA) or ("memberProfile.member_id == %@", memberA_id). If you want to fetch all comments of the selected post you create a fetch request with entity Comment and predicate ("memberPosts == %@", selectedPost).